# Navegação scroll em Bullets

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo um site one page scroll e queria que cada link e (bullets) que eu  clicasse ficasse ativo referente a página que eu estou.
[Esse é o exemplo que estou fazendo](http://se.mediagruppe.com/SE/MG/EXTRANET/experiments/site/)
o script do scroll não coloquei ainda mas queria deixar o efeito de clicar nos (bullets) prontos.

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">LOCALIZAÇÃO</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">APARTAMENTOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">LAZER</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="bg_bullets">
    <a href="index.html" class=""><div class="bullets_one active"> </div> </a>
    <a href="#" class=""><div class="bullets_two active"> </div> </a>
    <a href="#" class=""><div class="bullets_three active"> </div> </a> 
    <a href="#" class=""><div class="bullets_four active"> </div> </a> 
 </div>  

</nav>
```

```
#header-container .nav {
position: absolute;
top: 32px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
left:167px;
}
.header-container .nav li {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }
#header-container .bg_bullets{
top:40px;
position:absolute;

background:url(../IMAGES/bg_bulets.png) no-repeat;
width:590px;
height:30px;
    }
#header-container .bullets_one{
float: left;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
margin-right: 120px;
background: #FFF;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #D7D8DA;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
margin-top:-6px;    
margin-left:10px;
position:absolute;
    }
#header-container .bullets_one:active{
background:#CC9;    
    }
#header-container .bullets_one:hover, #header-container .bullets_three:hover, #header-container .bullets_four:hover {
background:#CC9;    
    }
```

Caso minha pergunta ainda esteja confusa eu tenho alguns exemplos:
[Exemplo 1](http://pacelaw.com/)
[Exemplo 2](http://clickbbo.com.br/)
[Exemplo 3](http://xmas.acc.cc/)

Comment: por favor mova seu exemplo pra algum site, tipo [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) o link que você postou não está abrindo aqui e pode sair do ar a qualquer momento invalidando sua pergunta no futuro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma classe `.active` aos seus `bullets` ao executar o evento que tens ao clica-los(`onClick`), **porém tens que remover a classe `.active` de todos eles também, para que não fiquem todos selecionados**

Que seria o seguinte:

```
$('.bg_bullets a div').click(function(){
  $('.bg_bullets a div').each(function(){
    $('.bg_bullets a div').removeClass('active');
  }); //remove todas as classes active dos bullets.
  $(this).addClass('active'); //adiciona classe active no elemento clicado
}); //evento do clique , provavelmente você já tem um porem pode usar dessa forma se quiser.
```

Aí você tem que declarar sua classe `.active` no seu CSS:

```
.active {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCC99; //peguei teu hover como exemplo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a ideia de acrescentar uma classe para o item ativo, segue um exemplo de como o código pode ser feito com jquery.
Vamos dar a classe bullet para os 'a', nesse caso ocodigo ficaria:

```
$('.bullet').click(function() { // seria melhor colocar uma classe padrão para esse 'a'
  $('.bullet').removeClass('active'); // remove a classe 'active' de todos
  $(this).addClass('active'); // adiciona a classe 'active' para o item selecionado
});
```

Comment: desta forma todos os links da página seriam afetados, não acho que seria a melhor solução. - alem disto não seriam os bullets para serem ativados e não os links?

Comment: Exatamente por isso sugeri que ele usasse uma classe padrão para esse 'a'. Alterarei ocódigo pra ficar mais claro então.

Answer (score -3):

```
$('.bg_bullets a div').click(function(){
  $('.bg_bullets a div').each(function(){
    $('.bg_bullets a div').removeClass('active');
  }); //remove todas as classes active dos bullets.
  $(this).addClass('active'); //adiciona classe active no elemento clicado
}); //evento do clique , provavelmente você já tem um porem pode usar dessa forma se quiser.

.active {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCC99; //peguei teu hover como exemplo
}
```

Comment: Talvez seja razoável explicar esse código e porque ele viria a resolver o problema.